# change LinearLayoutManager to GridLayoutManager

Tags: gridlayoutmanager, linearlayoutmanager

```js
private void setUpRecyclerView() {
recyclerView.setHasFixedSize(true);
recyclerView.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(this));
recyclerViewAdapter = new StoryAdapter(MainActivity.this, getData());
recyclerView.setAdapter(recyclerViewAdapter);
recyclerViewAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
}
private ArrayList<Object> getData() {
```

Good someone helps me implement gridlayoutmanager?

1 Photo so I have it

https://i.stack.imgur.com/ehbfZ.png

2 photo so I want to leave someone can help me?

https://i.stack.imgur.com/vbZLV.png
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LDuvw.png)

I leave the code in the comments thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Take a look here - https://medium.com/@alla.dubovska/android-recyclerview-animated-transition-between-grid-and-list-layouts-b2309e1d9f19

This article is about RecyclerView animated transition between Grid and List layouts.